# Reducing transfer fees from S3 buckets (multiple ones) to our datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, aws-direct-connect

I'm trying to lower egress fees from multiple S3 buckets in one AWS account (several Terabytes per month) to our US datacenter.

I thought of setting up a VPC on our AWS account, and using a [`Gateway Endpoint for S3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) and then having a [`Direct Connect`](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/pricing/) always active from our datacenter to our AWS VPC (and pay the usual hourly + GB transferred reduced fees).

After reading the documentation it is my understanding that I will **not** pay any traffic to use the `Gateway Endpoint for S3` since traffic never leaves AWS until it reaches our AWS VPC. To transfer it to our datacenter the usual hourly + GB transferred reduced fees for the `Direct Connect` is then billed.

Is this correct? Will we still be able to initiate a GET from our datacenter applications (through the `Direct Connect` to this VPC `Gateway Endpoint for S3` so that we can pull S3 files from the 3rd party AWS account that endpoint is linked to? (requests would *only* originate from our datacenter servers to get or sometimes put S3 files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to route to the gateway endpoint via direct connect. However, you can configure a public VIF on your direct connect to route all traffic to the Amazon IP spaces via the direct connect.

From: [Which type of virtual interface should I use to connect different resources in AWS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-private-interface-dx/)

> To connect to AWS resources that are reachable by a public IP address
> (such as an Amazon Simple Storage Service bucket) or AWS public
> endpoints, use a public virtual interface.

Alternatively you can use the recently released interface endpoint for S3 ([AWS Announcement - Amazon S3 now supports AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/amazon-s3-now-supports-aws-privatelink/)), to get this working you need to configure your application to use this endpoint. However this can maybe against your needs, because you will be charged a small fee for each GB processed by the interface endpoint. Therefore the AWS Direct Connect public VIF should be the right choice for you.